# Comma separation in output

Tags: c, function

How can I get comma in between the digits of a number given in a input like 1000,10000,100000,1000000  and it separates the digits of a number like
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000 as an output

Is any function(library) in C to make a program for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the non standard `'` print flag and setting locales:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int value = 1234567;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Locale not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%'d\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

But using *x mod 3*  and a [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) you can build your own (portable) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *thousand_sep(long x)
{
    char s[64], *p = s, *q, *r;
    int len;

    len = sprintf(p, "%ld", x);
    q = r = malloc(len + (len / 3) + 1);
    if (r == NULL) return NULL;
    if (*p == '-') {
        *q++ = *p++;
        len--;
    }
    switch (len % 3) {
        do {
            *q++ = ',';
            case 0: *q++ = *p++;
            case 2: *q++ = *p++;
            case 1: *q++ = *p++;
        } while (*p);
    }
    *q = '\0';
    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = thousand_sep(1234567);

    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1,234,567
```

**EDIT:**

> if i wish to make the same in java then??

Sorry, I don't kow Java, maybe useful (in javascript using regex's):

```
Number.prototype.thousand_sep = function(decs){
    var n = this.toFixed(decs).toString().split('.');

    n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    return n.join('.');
};
...
var x = 1234567;
alert(x.thousand_sep(0));
```

Comment: if i wish to make the same in java then??

Answer (score 0):

- For input, it's up to you to just read comma-separated integers. I would use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) and skip the comma manually.
- For output, add `'` to the proper `printf()` output specifier, i.e. `printf("%'d", 1000);` should print the `int` value `1000` as `1,000`. This depends on your locale, see [the manual page for details](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 0):

For java (as asked by the OP in a comment somewhere), use:

```
String formattedString = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(number);
```

If you need a specific locale:

```
String formattedString = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH).format(number);
```

If you need other number formatters (for currency, percent, so on):

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number);
NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(number);
NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(number);
```

[each of them can be passed a Locale to]

For greater control over formatting options you can switch to [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
new DecimalFormat("0,000.00").format(number);
```

I recommend you explore both classes (NumberFormat and DecimalFormat) to understand your possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any library that could solve this problem.

I have written some code to do the required operation.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void func (int in, char * modified_int)
{
    char my_int[1000];
    sprintf (my_int, "%d", in);
    int len = strlen(my_int);

    int curr_index = len + len/3 - 1;

    modified_int[curr_index+1] = '\0';
    int modulo_3 = 0;

    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--, curr_index--, modulo_3++)
    {
        char abc = my_int[i];
        modified_int[curr_index] = abc;
        if ((modulo_3 == 2) && (i != 0))
        {
            curr_index--;
            modified_int[curr_index] = ',';
            modulo_3 = -1;
        }

    }
}

int main ()
{
    char my_int[1000];
    int n = 1000;

    func(n, my_int);

    printf("%s\n", my_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if it does not solve your problem.