# Set thousands separator for C printf

Tags: c, printf, locale

I have this C code:

```
locale_t myLocale = newlocale(LC_NUMERIC_MASK, "en_US", (locale_t) 0);
uselocale(myLocale);
ptrLocale = localeconv();
ptrLocale->thousands_sep = (char *) "'";

int i1 = snprintf( s1, sizeof(s1), "%'d", 123456789);
```

The output in `s1` is `123,456,789`.

Even I set `->thousands_sep` to `'` it is ignored. Is there a way to set any character as the thousands separator?

Comment: Don't you need to call useLocale *after* you modify the local structure to pass the new data into the runtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629137/1606345

Comment: Ok. then it is not possible. I keep using my own function which does not use malloc and is thread safe as well.

Comment: I think for C the decision to write your own formatting function is a good idea.

Comment: @VolAnd I found a new, better solution which works in C on linux and I posted it as a new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution which works on each linux distribution and does not need - as my 1st answer - a `glibc` hack:

---

All these steps must be performed in the **origin** `glibc` directory - **NOT** in the build directory - after you built the `glibc` version using a separate build directory as suggested by this [instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html#Configuring-and-compiling).

My new `locale` file is called `en_AT`.

1. Create in the `localedata/locales/` directory from an existing file `en_US` a new file `en_AT` .
2. Change all entries for `thousands_sep` to `thousands_sep   "<U0027>"` or whatever character you want to have as the thousands separator.
3. Change inside of the new file all occurrences of `en_US` to `en_AT`.
4. Add to the file `localedata/SUPPORTED` the line: `en_AT.UTF-8/UTF-8 \`.
5. Run in the **build** directory `make localedata/install-locales`.
6. The new `locale` will be then automatically added to the system and is ***instantly*** accessible for the program.

---

In the C/C++ program you switch to the new thousands separator character with:

> `setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_AT.UTF-8" );`

using it with `printf( "%'d", 1000000 );` which produces this output

> 1'000'000

---

**Remark:** When you need in the program different localizations which are determinated while the runtime you can use this [example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/newlocale.3.html) from the `man` pages where you load the requested `locale` and just replace the `LC_NUMERIC` settings from `en_AT`.

Answer (score 2):

Function `localeconv()` just read locate settings, and `ptrLocale->thousands_sep` itself not changes that settings for current locale.

**EDIT:**

I do not know how to do this in C, but lots of examples with C++ output can be found.
See the following example in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

struct myseps : numpunct<char> { 
   // use ' as separator
   char do_thousands_sep() const { return '\''; } 

   // digits are grouped by 3
   string do_grouping() const { return "\3"; }
};

int main() {
  cout.imbue(locale(locale(), new myseps));
  cout << 1234567; // the result will be 1'234'567
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The C++ reference said:

> localeconv() returns a pointer to a filled-in object of type struct lconv. The values contained in the object can be overwritten by subsequent calls to localeconv and do not directly modify the object. Calls to setlocale with category values of LC_ALL, LC_MONETARY, or LC_NUMERIC overwrite the contents of the structure.

I tried the following example in MS Visual Studio 2012 (I understand that it is bad and unsafe style):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
    struct lconv *ptrLocale = localeconv();
    strcpy(ptrLocale->decimal_point, ":");
    strcpy(ptrLocale->thousands_sep, "'");
    char str[20];
    printf("%10.3lf \n", 13000.26);
    return 0;
}
```

and I saw the result:

```
  13000:260
```

therefore, it can be assumed that the changes of `decimal_point` and `thousands_sep` are possible through pointer received with `localeconv()`, but `printf` ignores `thousands_sep`.

**EDIT 3:**

Updated C++ example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct myseps : numpunct<char> { 
   // use ' as separator
   char do_thousands_sep() const { return '\''; } 

   // digits are grouped by 3
   string do_grouping() const { return "\3"; }
};

int main() {
  stringstream ss;
  ss.imbue(locale(locale(), new myseps));
  ss << 1234567;  // printing to string stream with formating
  printf("%s\n", ss.str().c_str()); // just output when ss.str() provide string, and c_str() converts it to char*
}
```

Comment: But which structure is `printf()` accessing? There must be a way how to override the thousand character. I diggered through the `printf()` from GNU glib library and it is not hardcoded there!

Comment: I suppose you need `setlocale()` function to change current locale

Comment: Also, check whether `snprintf` is locale-dependent function

Comment: @VoIAnd: Yes, but how do I set explicitly another thousand separator character? Calling `setlocale()` with a predefined locale "en_US", "de_DE", ... uses the separator as defined for the locale.

Comment: @AlBundy : I suppose, `printf`-family functions just ignore `ptrLocale->thousands_sep` settings. See **EDIT 2**

Comment: @VoIAnd: No, it does not. You get it with the ' flag and changing the locale from en_US to de_DE it also changes the character. I read the source code from GNU glib `printf()` and they respect it. My question is how do I get to the buffer for the thousand separator character so I can change it.

Comment: @Edit 2: This is funny. 1) In SLES I get Segmentation fault when I use `strcpy()` to overwrite it. 2) Try this format specifier: `printf("%'10.3lf\n", 13000.26);` - use the `'` character

Comment: That is really funny - `printf("%'10.3lf \n", 13000.26);` compiled with MSVS print out just `'10.3lf` .

Comment: Lets try another way: How can I in C++ use the `.imbue` functions but the result is returned as `std::string` or `char *` and I can provide more format specifier like this: `"%llu bytes loaded within %.4fms in thread #%03d"`

Comment: I can confirm the possibility to change the decimal separator, but could not find either how to use a thousand separator with `printf`.

Comment: BTW in my own tests, I did not use strcpy to set the decimal or thousand separator but simply `ptrLocale->decimal_point = ":"`. If thousand separator was empty string, using `strcpy` with a non empty source could lead to buffer overrun.

Comment: @VoIAnd: This is not exactly what I want. Using `imbue` is just another way as I had it till now with my self written functions. I have to think about it!

Comment: @those who are wondering how to use printf with thousand separators: you must `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");` see answer to: "How can I format currency with commas in C?"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695126/1973022 .

Answer (score 1):

This answer is derived from [VolAnd's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744888/3545273).

According to [this source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), the thousand separator in only used with the non standard `'` flag.

So if your `printf` is POSIX.1-2008 compatible, you could use :

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
struct lconv *ptrLocale = localeconv();
ptrLocale->decimal_point = ":";
ptrLocale->thousands_sep = "'";
char str[20];
printf("%'10.3lf \n", 13000.26);
return 0;
```

Comment: This is the code from my question where I am asking how to do it. Your code does not work for me. I have to use `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US");` in order to see at least the American thousand separator character.

Comment: @AlBundy : with this code, I could successfully change the decimal separator. Unfortunately, the two systems on which I tried it do not support the `'` non standard flag (whatever locale I use).

Comment: Note that it depends on which standard you choose as to whether it is standard or not.  POSIX specifies that [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) supports the `'` as indicating that the thousands separator should be printed appropriately.  Also, Mac OS X (10.10.5) and by inference BSD has a set of `_l` printing functions: `int printf_l(locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);` and `int fprintf_l(FILE * restrict stream, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);` for example.  These are the best way to go if they're available.

Comment: More seriously, note that the POSIX specification for [`localeconv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localeconv.html) explicitly says: _The `localeconv()` function need not be thread-safe. … The `localeconv()` function shall return a pointer to the filled-in object. The application shall not modify the structure to which the return value points, nor any storage areas pointed to by pointers within the structure._  A portable application may not do as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really very dirty hack how to change the thousand separator character for `printf()`:

1. Download the GNU libc.
2. run the `configure --prefix=/usr/glibc-version` command
3. run `make -j 8`
4. get the very long compiler command with all switches from the `make` output
5. write the C source file `setMyThousandSeparator.c` - content see below
6. compile this source file with the gcc switches from point 3.
7. in your normal C source code call `setMyThousandSeparator("'")` function before the `printf()` call.
8. link `setMyThousandSeparator.o` with your project.

For the moment I tried it when linking `libc` static but it works.

Content of `setMyThousandSeparator.c`:

```
#include <locale/localeinfo.h>

void setMyThousandSeparator(char * sMySeparator)
{
    _NL_CURRENT (LC_NUMERIC, THOUSANDS_SEP) = sMySeparator;
}
```

**Info:**
This solution is thread safe because it is accessing the same data as `printf()` does!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a specialized C function which I'm using for uint64_t type, but it can be easily generalized. Basically, it injects the thousand separators into the string produced by snprintf().

This method is independent on LOCALE, C-standard used, etc - and of course, You don't have to recompile the GNU libc ;)

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
   #define PRT_U64 "lu"
#else
   #define PRT_U64 "llu"
#endif

char* th_sep_u64(uint64_t val, char* buf) {
   char tmpbuf[32]; //18'446'744'073'709'551'615 -> 26 chars
   int  nch, toffs, pos;
   pos   = 1;
   toffs = 31;
   nch   = snprintf(tmpbuf, 32, "%"PRT_U64, val);
   nch  -- ;
   buf[toffs] = 0;

   for (; nch>=0; --nch) {
      toffs -- ;
      buf[toffs] = tmpbuf[nch];
      if ((0 == (pos % 3)) && (nch > 0)) {
         toffs -- ;
         buf[toffs] = '\''; //inject the separator
      }
      pos ++ ;
   }
   buf += toffs;
   return buf;
}
```

Usage:

```
{
   char     cbuf[32]; 
   uint64_t val = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFll;

   printf("%s", th_sep_u64(val, cbuf));

   //result: 18'446'744'073'709'551'615
}
```

Regards

Comment: This is a nice function but it becomes _tiresome_ when your format string contains lot of different formats. Recompiling GNU glibc can indeed become very tricky and I don't consider it as a good solution - 5 years later. Now, I solve it with building a new LOCALE which is really a very simple task and the huge advantage is, that the thousand separator works even in the Linux Bash command line so it becomes global.

Comment: Yeah, it all depends on what You need to achieve. I need to run my code on many machines, different OSes, so for me it would be _tiresome_ to build / install / change  LOCALE for each case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "just" add a new printf specifier:

```
static int printf_arginfo_M(const struct printf_info *info, size_t n, int *argtypes, int *size) {

    if ( info->is_long_double ) {               // %llM
        size[0] = sizeof(long long);
        if ( n > 0 ) argtypes[0] = PA_INT | PA_FLAG_LONG_LONG;
    }
    else if ( info->is_long ) {                 // %lM
        size[0] = sizeof(long);
        if ( n > 0 ) argtypes[0] = PA_INT | PA_FLAG_LONG;
    }
    else {
        size[0] = sizeof(int);                  // %M
        if ( n > 0 ) argtypes[0] = PA_INT;
    }

    return 1;
}

static int printf_output_M(FILE *stream, const struct printf_info *info, const void *const args[])
{
    long long number;

    if ( info->is_long_double ) {               // %llM
        number = *(const long long*)(args[0]);
    }
    else if ( info->is_long ) {                 // %lM
        number = *(const long*)(args[0]);
    }
    else {                                      // %M
        number = *(const int*)(args[0]);
    }

    long long value = (number < 0) ? -number : number;
    int len;
    char buf[32];
    char *pos = &buf[31];
    int i = 0;

    *pos = '\0';

    do {
        if ( (i % 3 == 0) && (i > 0) ) *--pos = '.';
        *--pos = '0' + value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        i++;
    } while (value > 0);

    if (number < 0) *--pos = '-';

    len = fprintf(stream, "%s", pos);

    return len;
}
```

Usage:

```
register_printf_specifier('M', printf_output_M, printf_arginfo_M);

printf("%M\n", -1234567890);
printf("%lM\n", -1234567890123456789l);
printf("%llM\n", -1234567890123456789ll);
```

The downside is, gcc complains about the new specifier so that you might want to disable these warnings:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-extra-args"
```